# Rails 3 generate scaffold for specific actions only

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My setup: Rails 3.0.9, Ruby 1.9.2

I wish to generate a scaffold only for the create action, what's the syntax for that? I'm guessing it's something I append to

```
rails g scaffold Project name:string ...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't believe you can. I'm looking at the generator and I see nothing related to using an option to limit the template.

[Generator](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.9/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/scaffold_controller/scaffold_controller_generator.rb)

[Template](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.9/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/scaffold_controller/templates/controller.rb)

Comment: I was afraid of that, I'm amazed that Rails doesn't have a way to do this though.

Answer (score 5):

Rails scaffolding is a very basic tool, it's not meant to be relied on, once you get a handle on the way rails works. However, you can use Ryan Bates' nifty-generator gem to generate scaffolds with greater control. Example:

```
rails g nifty:scaffold post name:string index new edit
```

Learn more here. https://github.com/ryanb/nifty-generators